# How to create summary tables and graphs in R by looping through the response variables (in columns)

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have a dataset with multiple response variables and three treatments. Treatment2 is nested within treatment1 and treatment3 is nested within treatment 2. I have shown only three response variables for the sake of simplicity. I would like to run this over 22 response variable of which 3 are shown in the demo table.

My objective:

1. To visualize how the response variable(s) change based on the treatment combination. I have created a script to perform this on one response variable. I am copy pasting this code to run through other columns which to me is an extremely crude way to do it. Which leads to my second objective.
2. Automate or modify the following script so that it can automatically loops through the column and produce desired table and graphs.

Demo data:
[demo.table](http://pastebin.com/sR2MvBBA)

Here is my script:

```
library(doBy)
length2 <- function (x, na.rm=FALSE) {
    if (na.rm) sum(!is.na(x))
    else       length(x)
}
 attach (demo)
cdataNA <- summaryBy(tyr ~ spp + wat + ins, data=demo, FUN=c(length2,mean,sd), na.rm=TRUE)
# Rename column change.length to just N
names(cdataNA)[names(cdataNA)=="tyr.length2"] <- "N"
# Calculate standard error of the mean
cdataNA$tyr.SE <- cdataNA$tyr.sd / sqrt(cdataNA$N)
cdataNA
# Now create a barplot using ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(cdataNA, aes(x = wat, y = tyr.mean, fill = ins))
b <- a + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + facet_grid (~ spp)
# Now put errorbars.
c <- b + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=tyr.mean-tyr.SE, ymax=tyr.mean+tyr.SE), 
                  width=.2,                    # Width of the error bars
                  position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
xlab ("wat") + 
ylab ("tyr (PA/PA std)")
c

## esc
library(doBy)
length2 <- function (x, na.rm=FALSE) {
    if (na.rm) sum(!is.na(x))
    else       length(x)
}
cdataNA1 <- summaryBy(esc ~ spp + wat + ins, data=demo, FUN=c(length2,mean,sd), na.rm=TRUE)
# Rename column change.length to just N
names(cdataNA1)[names(cdataNA1)=="esc.length2"] <- "N"
# Calculate standard error of the mean
cdataNA1$esc.SE <- cdataNA1$esc.sd / sqrt(cdataNA1$N)
cdataNA1
# Now create a barplot using ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
a1 <- ggplot(cdataNA1, aes(x = wat, y = esc.mean, fill = ins))
b1 <- a1 + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + facet_grid (~ spp)
# Now put errorbars.
c1 <- b1 + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=esc.mean-esc.SE, ymax=esc.mean+esc.SE), 
                  width=.2,                    # Width of the error bars
                  position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
xlab ("wat") + 
ylab ("esc (PA/PA std)")
c1
```

Resulting table for tyr:

```
  spp  wat ins N tyr.mean      tyr.sd      tyr.SE
1  Bl High  No 4 0.305325 0.034102041 0.017051020
2  Bl High Yes 5 0.186140 0.045165894 0.020198802
3  Bl  Low  No 5 0.310540 0.061810096 0.027642315
4  Bl  Low Yes 5 0.202840 0.029034944 0.012984822
5 Man High  No 4 0.122725 0.075867005 0.037933503
6 Man High Yes 5 0.081800 0.013463469 0.006021046
7 Man  Low  No 5 0.079880 0.009569587 0.004279650
8 Man  Low Yes 4 0.083550 0.018431947 0.009215973
```

Resulting graph for esc:
[demo figure for esc](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/escdemo.png/)

So the whole thing works but still requires considerable manual labor which impedes the work-flow. it would be great to achieve automation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: melt your data so that the different response variables are levels in an additional categorical predictor variable ...

Comment: @BenBolker: Let me understand it clearly. Are you asking me to melt the data for 3 (or 22) response variable to one column with a predictor variable, let say comp -> containing tyr..., esc..., and esc.R? If I do that my length2 function no longer remains valid, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can organize the data in just two lines:

```
melt.dta <- melt(dta, id.vars = c("spp", "wat", "ins"), measure.vars = "tyr")
cast(melt.dta, spp + wat + ins ~ ., 
     function (x) c("N" = sum(!is.na(x)), 
                    "mean" = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),                   
                    "sd" = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE),
                    "se" = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x)))))
```

It returns:

```
  spp  wat ins N   mean      sd      se
1  Bl High  No 4 0.3053 0.03410 0.01705
2  Bl High Yes 5 0.1861 0.04517 0.02020
3  Bl  Low  No 5 0.3105 0.06181 0.02764
4  Bl  Low Yes 5 0.2028 0.02903 0.01298
5 Man High  No 4 0.1227 0.07587 0.03793
6 Man High Yes 5 0.0818 0.01346 0.00602
7 Man  Low  No 5 0.0799 0.00957 0.00428
8 Man  Low Yes 4 0.0835 0.01843 0.00922
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your script is a lot cleaner than mine. "tyr" works. However, when I executed `myDta(dta, c("spp", "wat", "ins"), "esc")`, I got `Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(result) & data_col, value = c(0,  : 
  rhs is the wrong length for indexing by a logical matrix
Calls: myDta ... reshape1 -> add.all.combinations -> [<- -> [<-.data.frame`. Did you run your script on other columns (esc and sec_R) to see if you can get an output? Second question was: how can I push my ggplot2 code to get automated graphs on all response variables?